# What's the difference between Interface and InstanceType<typeof Class> when as a type of variable?

Tags: typescript

For example:

`HttpService.ts`:

```js
export interface IHttpService {
  request(): Promise<any>;
  formPostRequest(): any;
}

export class HttpService implements IHttpService {
  public async request() {
    //
  }

  public formPostRequest() {
    //
  }
}
```

Now, I will use `HttpService` according to dependency injection. Like this:

`GoogleAccount.ts`:

```js
import { HttpService } from './HttpService';

class GoogleAccount {
  private httpService: InstanceType<typeof HttpService>;
  constructor(httpService: InstanceType<typeof HttpService>) {
    this.httpService = httpService;
  }

  public findGoogleAccountById(id: string) {
    return this.httpService.request();
  }
}
```

Above code uses `InstanceType` and `typeof` predefined types of `TypeScript` as the type of `httpService`

Another way which I often use is to use `interface` as the type of `httpService`, like this:

```js
import { IHttpService } from './HttpService';

class GoogleAccount2 {
  private httpService: IHttpService;
  constructor(httpService: IHttpService) {
    this.httpService = httpService;
  }

  public findGoogleAccountById(id: string) {
    return this.httpService.request();
  }
}
```

Both of them works fine under the type system of `TypeScript`. `tsc` doesn't complaint type error. So, what's the difference between them when as a static type of variable?

Maybe it's not necessary use `InstanceType<typeof HttpService>` for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that it is not necessary to use `InstanceType<typeof HttpService>` If you know the underlying interface you need to implement. 
InstanceType usage should be restricted to cases where you can't get the underlying type directly. Here are some good usecases [Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25998#issuecomment-471367329)

Comment: Thanks. The documentation of `InstanceType` should be added to the official site of typescript. Especially the use cases for it.

Comment: Yes, I agree. In the link I shared, that is what is troubling the people. I chanced upon the example when I went on a tangent and wanted to find out if there was any official documentation which illustrate the use cases. You should also comment there to let them know you faced this issue because of no documentation